# iOS customize morenavigationcontroller

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I want to add an `UIImageView` on the top of the `UITableView` generated in the MoreNavigationController. To do this I need to change the `UITableView`'s position and size.

Here is the code I tried:

```
UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"barre.png"]];
    [img setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, img.frame.size.height)];
    [self.tabBarController.moreNavigationController.view addSubview:img];
    [[[self.tabBarController.moreNavigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] view] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 320, 320, 300)];
```

The image is added but the tableview size and position don't change. I also tried:

```
[self.tabBarController.moreNavigationController.topViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 320, 320, 300)];
```